# policy in laravel always unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel

i am try to make policy in Post Model, i follow the documentation but still return always false
in api.php

```
Route::put('post/{id}','PostController@update')->middleware('auth:api');
```

in post controller

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post,$id){
        $this->authorize('update',$post);

        $request->validate(['content'=>'required']);
        $post = $post->find($id);
        $post->content = $request->content;
        $post->save();

return response()->json($post, 200);
}
```

in PostPolicy

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post)
  {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
  }
```

in AuthServiceProvider

```
protected $policies = [
        'App\Post' => 'App\Policies\PostPolicy',
];
```

please ignore for model since model is working properly, if i comment $this->authorize in controller is working, but there is no authentication, user can update any thing in model

i test from postman using api using

```
authorization = Bearer 'api_token'
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're having this issue is because the update method in the policy expects a loaded instance of the model, however, with your current setup, you're passing an unloaded/empty instance of the model.

You could get around this by using [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding). Change `{id}` in your route to be `{post}`:

```
Route::put('post/{post}','PostController@update')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Then remove the `$id` argument from your `update()` method:

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $post);

    $request->validate(['content' => 'required']);

    $post->content = $request->content;
    $post->save();

    return response()->json($post, 200);
}
```

Also, notice now how you're not having to use `find` to load the model, this is because Laravel is loading the model for you under-the-hood.

Route model binding works by looking for a param name with the same name as the uri segment i.e. `{post}` on the route and `$post` the method argument, and since `$post` is type-hinted to be a model Laravel knows to use the value of `{post}` to load (find) the `Post` model.